# How do I lock the axis in the animation window while dragging?

Tags: unity, animation

I want to drag one or more keyframe curve edit points in the horizontal direction only.

Here is a rough screenshot of what I'm trying to do.

As one can see, I'm having a hard time moving the keyframes horizontally only.

Is there a way to lock the movement so that I can only move it horizontally?

[image: example of unlocked movement]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start dragging, *then* press the shift key.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!